# Pagination with total row count in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, pagination, hql

I am trying to paginate a simple query using HQL, and retrieve the total row count as part of the same query.

My query is simple enough...

```
var members = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateQuery(@"
    select m
    from ListMember as m
    join fetch m.Individual as i") 
    .SetFirstResult(pageIndex*pageSize)
    .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
    .List<ListMember>();
```

The Individual is mapped as a many-to-one on the ListMember class. This works great. The pagination works as expected and generates the following Sql...

```
SELECT   TOP ( 10 /* @p0 */ ) DirPeerG1_1_0_,
                 Director1_0_1_,
                 Director2_1_0_,
                 Forename2_0_1_,    
                 Surname0_1_
FROM     (SELECT listmember0_.DirPeerGrpMemberID    as DirPeerG1_1_0_,
             listmember1_.DirectorKeyID         as Director1_0_1_,
             listmember0_.DirectorKeyId         as Director2_1_0_,
             listmember1_.Forename1             as Forename2_0_1_,
             listmember1_.Surname               as Surname0_1_,
             ROW_NUMBER()
               OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row
          FROM   tblMembers listmember0_
             inner join tblIndividuals listmember1_
               on listmember0_.DirectorKeyId = listmember1_.DirectorKeyID) as query
WHERE    query.__hibernate_sort_row > 10 /* @p1 */
ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

I read this article posted by Ayende called [Paged data + Count(*) with NHibernate: The really easy way!](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/04/27/Paged-data--Count-with-NHibernate-The-really-easy-way.aspx), so I tried to implement it in my query.

I followed the steps in the article to add the custom HQL function called `rowcount()`, and changed my query to this...

```
var members = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateQuery(@"
    select m, rowcount()
    from ListMember as m
    join fetch m.Individual as i") 
    .SetFirstResult(pageIndex*pageSize)
    .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
    .List<ListMember>();
```

The Sql that is generated is almost correct, however it includes one of the columns twice resulting in this error...

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   The column '...' was specified
>   multiple times for 'query'.

The Sql it generates looks like this...

```
SELECT   TOP ( 10 /* @p0 */ ) 
         col_0_0_, 
         col_1_0_, 
         Director1_0_1_, 
         DirPeerG1_1_0_, 
         Director1_0_1_, 
         Director2_1_0_, 
         Forename2_0_1_,    
         Surname0_1_
FROM     (SELECT 
      listmember0_.DirPeerGrpMemberID as col_0_0_, 
      count(*) over() as col_1_0_, 
      listmember1_.DirectorKeyID as Director1_0_1_, 
      listmember0_.DirPeerGrpMemberID as DirPeerG1_1_0_, 
      listmember1_.DirectorKeyID as Director1_0_1_, 
      listmember0_.DirectorKeyId as Director2_1_0_, 
      listmember1_.Forename1 as Forename2_0_1_, 
      listmember1_.Surname as Surname0_1_, 
             ROW_NUMBER()
               OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row
          FROM   RCMUser.dbo.tblDirPeerGrpMembers listmember0_
             inner join RCMAlpha.dbo.tblDirectorProfileDetails listmember1_
               on listmember0_.DirectorKeyId = listmember1_.DirectorKeyID) as query
WHERE    query.__hibernate_sort_row > 10 /* @p1 */
ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

For some reason it includes the `Director1_0_1_` column twice in the projection, which causes this error. This Sql is frustratingly close to what I would like, and I’m hoping an NHibernate expert out there can help explain why this would happen.

### Suggestions Tried

Thanks to the suggestion from @Jason . I tried it with the non-generic version of .List() method to execute the query but this unfortunately also produced the same Sql with the duplicate column...

```
var members = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateQuery(@"
    select m, rowcount()
    from ListMember as m
    join fetch m.Individual as i")
    .SetFirstResult(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
    .List()
    .Cast<Tuple<ListMember, int>>()
    .Select(x => x.First);
```

### Update

It doesn't look like this is going to be possible without getting into the NH source code. My solution requirements have changed and I am no longer going to pursue the answer.

In summary, the solution would be to either...

- Use Futures or MultiQuery to execute two statements in a single command - one to retrieve the page of data and one the total row count.
- Modify your pagination solution to do without a total result count - Continuous scrolling for example.

Comment: How would you access the rowcount field from the List of ListMembers? Might be easier to use futures and batch 2 queries (rowcount and page) together.

Comment: Many thanks @dotjoe. Before trying to use this technique did actually have it working using futures in the documented way, and I got the behaviour I wanted. The thing I didn't like was that both queries had to have the same FROM, JOIN and WHERE sections in order to work with the same dataset, and I was under the impression (possibly incorrectly) that this was doubling up some of the work and therefore could be improved performance-wise. I would be very interested to know if this is not the case. Maybe SqlServer caches part of the first page query for use in the count query when batched?

Comment: @dotjoe. As for your question on how I would retrieve the rowcount. I must admit I have not given this as much thought as it needs, but I was hoping to use a custom ResultTransformer to somehow separate the object tuple from the rowcount tuple. I'm not even sure this will be possible anyway :-(

Comment: Oh, as far as duplicating your efforts for the 2 future queries. You can use the `ToRowCountQuery()` method right before you set the paging/projection bits. This will Clone the query so you'll have the same where clause for both.

Comment: I have recently come across `ToRowCountQuery()` and it certainly would allow me to reuse the query. But my concern was more about the extra work that the database server has to do to execute a batch of two queries as opposed to a single one that also returns the total row count.

Comment: Database server is really good at it though :) I wouldn't worry about it. Is the `count(*) over()` even supported by all the major rdbms?

Comment: Ok that's good to know. I suspect this command is specific to Sql, although similar ones may exist on other database technologies. I don't know and currently I'm only concerned vwith the SqlServer dialect so that's ok.

Comment: Hey Andy, I'm having the same issue... did you ever come up with a usable solution?

Comment: In sort, no. Our requirements changes such that we didn't need it. But we have since had to use the first option that I mention in the "Update" section in the question. Executing two queries was the simplest way to go and performance isn't affected too much. The solution can be wraped up within your repository so that all the details are hidden from you service layer.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, one issue is that you're using a ListMember-typed List method.  In the example at the page you linked, he uses List() which returns a list of tuples.  The first item of your tuple would be a ListMember and the second would be the row count.  That List<> might affect your query and would probably throw an exception even if it did return.

Try using:

```
var tuples = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateQuery(@"
select m, rowcount()
from ListMember as m
join fetch m.Individual as i") 
.SetFirstResult(pageIndex*pageSize)
.SetMaxResults(pageSize)
.List();

var members = tuples.Select<Tuple<ListMember, int>, ListMember>(x => x.Item1);
```

but I kinda agree with @dotjoe.  A MultiQuery might be easier.  It's what I use.  Here's a a good [link](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/05/NHibernateMutliQuerySupport.aspx) about it from the same author you linked to before (Ayende).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Json. It was definitely worth a try but it still results in the same Sql with the duplicate column. I think I will have to revert back to my batch of 2 queries for this.